# Ubuntu cloud with four servers

Tags: server, vmware, cloud, openstack

I searched a lot about this question before ask, sorry for the title being so short and generic at the same time, but my problem is more related to a merge from a noob and expertise.

I have 4 (four) servers, all Dell, with 32GB RAM Xeon etc... I would like to build a Private Cloud, where these machines run together creating one super server, to be able to install several Virtual Machines (VirtuaBox or VMWare) and at the config from these VM set how much RAM and Processors it can be using at these VM, but these are numbers calculated from all my servers.

Is this possible or I´m trying something impossible for now? I searched and found that Cloud is only possible with 6 servers, but is it possible with 4?

Best regard´s. Sorry for my bad english, I made my best!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which implementation of cloud middleware you are referring to, but [openstack](http://www.openstack.org) supports building clouds from a single VM or laptop up to multi-node hardware installations. Check out their [tutorials](http://devstack.org/) for privately deployed clouds.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning it, I forget. I´m open to use any solution you recomend, CloudStack, OpenStack or Eucalyptus, just want to build a private cloud to reduce my servers usage and deploy VM to them so I´m able to run more than one service separated.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuCloudInfrastructure is this ok to be used? Or is something different from my approach? Thanks